# Reduce Two Functions to a Single Function. Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a module to toggle between reading and unread messages using Flask. I have a button that toggles between reading and unread a message of which I have implemented. However I've tried writing the ways to handle this as a single function, I haven't succeeded

**These are the two routes:**

I'll omit the routing line

```
def read(msg_id):
    msg = Messages.query.filter_by(id=msg_id).first()

    msg.status = True
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(redirect_url())
```

**And**

```
def unread(msg_id):
    msg = Messages.query.filter_by(id=msg_id).first()

    msg.status = False
    db.session.commit()
    
    return redirect(redirect_url())
```

The message by default is False, indicating an unread message.

Then on my template, I do this ;

```
                {% if msg.status == False %}
                <th scope="row"> <i class="bi bi-bell-fill text-danger"></i> </th>
                {% else %}
                <th scope="row"> <i class="bi bi-check2-circle text-success"></i> </th>
                {% endif %}
```

How can I rewrite the above two functions as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to toggle the status, so set it to the value it is not.

```py
def toggle_read(msg_id):
    msg = Messages.query.filter_by(id=msg_id).first()

    msg.status = not msg.status
    db.session.commit()
    
    return redirect(redirect_url())
```

However, in practice this might lead to the UI being confusing if it's open in two tabs, or there are two people looking at the status, or there's a network error. This is because `toggle` isn't idempotent (to be idempotent applying it twice would be the same as applying it once).

The other option would be for it to take a parameter for the new status:

```py
def set_read(msg_id, status):
    msg = Messages.query.filter_by(id=msg_id).first()

    msg.status = status == "True"
    db.session.commit()
    
    return redirect(redirect_url())
```